# RicheditBox doesn't load ANSI encoded Document

Tags: uwp

RichEditBox doesn't load ANSI encoded Document but it loads all other unicode encoded text Documents. Here is the code below

```cs
FileOpenPicker fileopenpicker = new FileOpenPicker();
fileopenpicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
fileopenpicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
fileopenpicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

OpenedStorageFile = await fileopenpicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

if (OpenedStorageFile != null)
{
    try
    {
        IRandomAccessStream randomAccStream = await OpenedStorageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        EditorRichEditBox.Document.LoadFromStream(TextSetOptions.None, randomAccStream);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);
        await md.ShowAsync();
 }
```

Comment: Why not just convert the text in memory before calling `LoadFromStream` (and pass the results as a new stream)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use StreamReader and EditorRichEditBox.Document.SetText will help you to read both ANSI and unicode encoded text document.

```
FileOpenPicker fileopenpicker = new FileOpenPicker();
fileopenpicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
fileopenpicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
fileopenpicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

StorageFile OpenedStorageFile = await fileopenpicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

if (OpenedStorageFile != null)
{
    try
    {
        IRandomAccessStream randomAccStream = await OpenedStorageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        var st = randomAccStream.AsStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(st);
        string s = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        EditorRichEditBox.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.None, s);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);
        await md.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't the solution as it adds entry to undo of richeditbox. Loading of initial items should not be able to be undone.